# how to check for every 12 th characters should be , in the String using Regex Pattern?

Tags: java, regex

Hi I want to check the String should contain a comma `,` in every 12 the character using Matcher and Pattern in java. I have used `^([a-zA-Z0-9\\-?\\,])+$` this pattern is not working for my requirement can anyone provide solution on this.
Here is my code:

```
package com.ibm.rock;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test{

      private Pattern pattern;
      private Matcher matcher;


 private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN ="^([a-zA-Z0-9]{11},)*[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,11}$";


      public Test(){
          pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
      }

      /**
       * Validate hex with regular expression
       * @param hex hex for validation
       * @return true valid hex, false invalid hex
       */
      public boolean validate(final String hex){
          System.out.println(hex.length());
          String value=hex.trim().replaceAll(" ","");


          matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
                  System.out.println("matcher:"+matcher);
          return matcher.matches();
          }else{
              return  false;
          }

      }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("ProjectsValidation::"+new Test().validate("IN-07-00177 , IN-07-00533"));

      }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?  Are you trying to look for a specific character every 12th character?  Or are you trying to look for a series of characters?  An example of what you're trying to find would help a lot.

Comment: Am looking for a ',' for every 12 th character in the String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're only looking for every 12th character, you can keep it pretty simple:

```
/^(.{11},)*.{0,11}$/
```

If you want **no** commas *except* at the 12th positions, try

```
/^([^,]{11},)*[^,]{0,11}$/
```

Comment: Question is, if the String is "ok", OP wants it match or not? my understanding of the question is, he doesn't want it match. but your regex says ok.

Comment: Thanks BryanH,This is working for every 12 th character should be , and even it should allow only [a-zA-Z0-9\\-] in before 12 the character,how to add this in regex pattern.

Comment: Hi BryanH I have modified the given the regex pattern as follows ^([a-zA-Z0-9\\-^,]{11},)*[a-zA-Z0-9\\-^,]{0,11}$ and it's working...Thanks A lot.

Comment: @kent you have a valid point. In that case, changing the first asterisk (match 0 or more) to a plus (match 1 or more) should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understood correctly you want to check that in a particular String every 12-th element is a comma? If yes, then this simple regex will work:

```
String input = "qazwsxedcrf,1234567890 ,";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.{11},)+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
System.out.println(m.matches());
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the question:

- check every 12th character, it must be ",". even if it is the last
  character of the string.
- the String should contain at least 12 characters, if less, not
  matched

so

```
"abcd"  - NOT Match
"12345678901,xx" - not match
"12345678901,10987654321" - not match
"12345678901" - not match
"12345678901,10987654321," match!
```

I hope I understood it correctly.

then:

```
^(\w{11},)+$
```

should work. note that the '\w' could be changed to fit your requirement.

Comment: Not sure if the requirement was the string length must be a multiple of 12 characters. If no, then I believe example two returns false unexpectedly.

Answer (score -1):

Try this regex:

```
^([a-zA-Z...]{11},)*[a-zA-Z...]{0,11}$
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{11}` and `{0,11}` at the end?

Comment: @biziclop well spotted, fixed.

Comment: @Kent Why is `abc` not a valid string? There was no requirement that the string contain any commas or have a minimum length, just that every 12th charaqcter is a comma.